Can I safely delete over 10,000 files in G:\$Recycle.bin put there by R?
There are 10,748 files and 412,150,599 bytes in G:$Recycle.bin, almost all of which were put there by R.  R and R-Studio are installed on G:.  Most of the files have R4.2.0 in the file name; I am using R 4.4.0.  What would be the harm in emptying G:$Recycle.bin?
Thank you in advance for your help.

What makes you think those were put there by R?  I think a more likely cause is that you (or someone else if it's a shared computer) moved R 4.2.0 to the recycle bin.  Generally when R deletes a file, it just deletes it.

I don't know whether you can safely delete them but to empty the recycle bin right click the Recycle Bin icon on the Windows desktop and choose Empty.  (On my Windows machine there are no entries that are identified as associated with R in the recycle bin.)
